# Why clone function is working when it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript

I found this snippet and it deep copies javascript array.

```
const makeCopy = (items) = items.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? clone(item) : item);
```

I have this array I am making a copy of

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

After making a copy I assign it to another array

```
const b = makeCopy(a);
```

It copies things correctly. But if I say in Javascript file

```
clone(anyArrayVar);
```

Javascript reports *clone is not defined*. Why is this happening when the function above is using `clone(item)`.
Please ellaborate.

Comment: Your original function shouldn't work either. It should be a recursive call, so it should be `makeCopy` and not `clone`.

Comment: Where is this `clone` function

Comment: `clone` isn't actually working, its being ignored since item is never an array. In the example, item is 1,2,3,4 or 5 none of which are arrays

Comment: @Aplet123 it is not a recursive call. I tested it. Then I posted the question.

Comment: As @imvain2 mentions, a number is not an array. So `Array.isArray(item)` returns false, and the map is to the number itself, as it should be. Your `clone()` function never gets called. So when you do call it explictly, its not surprising it fails, since it doesn't exist.

Comment: @HassanJaved you misinterpreted what Aplet said. You keep switching the functions `makeCopy` and `clone`. You only defined `makeCopy`, you never defined `clone`.

Comment: Small note: You could clone an array simply by assigning another variable to its value, e.g. `var a = [1, 2, 3]; var b = a;`

Comment: @Lemondoge, no that does not clone the array in any sense. If you then mutate either of them, it will affect the other the same way.

Comment: No @Lemondoge, that is not cloning the array, thats just assigning a reference. The OP is trying to make a Deep-Copy function.

Comment: Yes, @imvain2. you are right. It is not being called. Yes, I added an array inside (nested array) and it failed.

Comment: @HassanJaved - as others have pointed out, the only reason you're not running into the error about `clone` not being defined is because you're not testing with a case that requires it. If you try to clone a nested array, such as `[1, [2, 3], [4, 5]]`, you will see this function error. The `clone` should be `makeCopy`. (But it still won't work correctly if you have an array containing any non-array objects.)

Comment: So this function technically takes an array, checks if the element is a simple element, and returns it. If it is array again it passes the array to itself and recursively does the job. Thank you sir for the elaboration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clone` isn't actually working, it's being ignored since item is never an array. In the example, item is 1,2,3,4 or 5 none of which are arrays.

Here is an update to it so it becomes recursive and takes arrays in arrays into consideration.

```js
function makeCopy(items) {
  return items.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? makeCopy(item) : item);
}

console.log(makeCopy([1, [2, 3], 4, 5]))
```